# Twitter share quote button will not work when there is a semicolon in my quote

Tags: html, twitter

I'm trying to set up a twitter share quote button, and I got it to work with my other quotes, but it will not work with my quote that has a semicolon in the actual quote.

```
 <a href="http://twitter.com/home/?status=Don\'t talk about yourself\; it will be done when you leave. -Wilson Mizner" class="btn btn-default btn-primary twitter">Tweet</a>
```

Does anyone know why it will only try and tweet half the quote and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it needs to be URL-encoded. So the semicolon `;` needs to be transformed to `%3B` in your URL.